# disable access to repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to disable for a while access to one of my repositories. Lets call this "repo1".
Im using tortoise and after I commented out whole part responsible for repo1 in my subversion.conf file (apache) on the server Im still able to make tortoise updates.
Which is weird because I can't reach that repo through browser, or I can't create new repo with this address.
Is there something else I have to do besides that conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally done using [hook scripts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.html).

Try something like this as a [pre-commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) hook:

```
#!/bin/sh 

echo "Repository is currently read only." >&2
exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use authz file for restricting access to the repository .

> [/]

```
* =
```

You need to point your AuthzSVNAccessFile variable(within httpd.conf) to authz file location.